# The smallest Linux that can support VMWare Workstation and networking

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

Setting aside the hardware, this is what I need to do: install the smallest possible Linux, but it can support this three features:

- Connect to a network using Ethernet
- Firewall
- Support VMWare Workstation 11

The idea is to save resources (memory, CPU, disk, etc.) for use by the VMWare virtual machines with Linux and Windows.

Maybe I can install a RedHat, CentOS, etc. and uninstall/disable features, but I think there should be a distribution that is already simple.

What do you recommend?

**EDIT:** I don't know if this is important, but the PC where I will install Linux has a Intel Core 2 Duo, two monitors, 8GB RAM, 120GB SSD, 180GB HDD, and 1TB USB external HDD.

Comment: You may want to modify your question - answering the question you asked (ie smallest) implies things which are out of scope of a standard distro - for a start recompiling the kernel and libraries to cut out stuff - in reality though the huge amount of time this will take is almost certainly not worth the cost - at least not for a single (or even small farm) of servers.  Maybe a better question would be what distro - but that falls into the realm of software advice and outside scope of SU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The large majority of Linux is Fedora or Debian like, and a non-GUI install will use negligible memory(1MB), CPU(10Hz), and disk(3GB).
So just install the "server version" (non-GUI) of any of the supported distributions.

http://store.vmware.com/store/vmware/en_US/pd/productID.310139000

```
VMware Workstation runs on most 64-bit Windows or Linux host operating systems :
Windows 8
Windows 7
Windows Server 2012
Windows Server 2008
Ubuntu 10.04 and above
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.8 and above
CentOS 5.8 and above
Oracle Linux 5.8 and above
openSUSE 11.2 and above
SUSE Linux 11.2 and above
```